Can't catch insets in Android
I'm going crazy with this, been at it for two days. I just want to draw to the whole screen :). I finally figured out that my bitmap is being drawn shifted a bit, and its shifted by this inset for the camera notch. Every approach I tried to get insets, get cut outs always told me there are zero cutouts. But during debug I see this log message:
InsetsController D  onStateChanged: InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 2400, 1080), mDisplayCutout=DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(88, 0 - 0, 0) 

and there's the 88pixel cutout.  But for the life of me I can't figure out how to access it. I tried a variety of different listener approaches in my main activity, and looking for insets and cutouts in my jetpack compose view where I'm doing my drawing but so far nothing.
Is there a way to listen for this system message or something like that?
thank you

"But for the life of me I can't figure out how to access it" -- have you tried WindowInsets?

yes it comes back as the cuts are all zero
